# Getting the last commit ID via a curl command to a git repo URL

Tags: git, curl, git-commit

How can I invoke the URL https://git.appfactorypreview.wso2.com/history/apiapp.git/ as shown in the documentation http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/? I mean, what is the CURL command that I have to give?

Answer (score 1):

The github REST api is **not** for *git*, its for *github.com* only.  *git* is a distributed version control system while *github.com* is a source code hosting service.

The repo url you have given is not from github. So github API will not work here. What you can do is clone the repo in a directory and invoke `git log -n 1`